# TOTAL in bar chart in qlikview

Tags: qlikview

I have this graph chart bar in `Qlikview`, the expression is:

```
INTERV= Sum(Quantity)/Count(Number)
```

and we can see the total for the first period is: 3450.76, i want to manipulate the total so as to calculate the total for each segment: the first segment is A: 192.70. I did `Sum(TOTAL<Segment> INTERV)` but it doesn't work to have the total I obtain 0 .

Your help is very apprciated

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for a total for each value? In this instance it would not be possible as Qlikview is removing the text that it cannot show as the sections are too small.

You can increase the chart size so the overall area is larger, remove the stacking option or I would suggest having a separate Table chart to display these values alongside your graph.

Here are the options that can configure the different totals

For each category within a month (as you have at the moment) you enable this option.
[image]

Whilst to only have the total per month, this is on the expression tab.
[image]

Comment: I don't mean that, sorry for my english but i want a field to calculate the total i don't want display in bar but just the total i want to calculate it by myself because here, it's calculating automatically

Comment: Not a problem, Where do you want to see the total? In the graph or separately? Do you want to see the total for each month or for the overall chart?

Comment: Yes I want to see the total for each month in the graph, because I want to have the ability to calculate with that total number.thank you

Comment: Yeah, That what I did! the number: 4600 I want to calculate by my self, the purpose when I get that number 4600, i can use it to calculate the pourcentage of each A, B , C D per month

Comment: Yeah but when i did this i get the false number, I don't know why